# obtener un valor especifico de un json

Tags: php, jquery, json

estoy realizando la lectura de un archivo el cual lo paso a json para poder ser cargado por ajax en mi vista

el codigo PHP que utilizo es este

```
<?php
$pais = $_POST['pais'];


if (is_file("PAIS/".$pais."/EMISORAS.json")) {
    $datos_emisora = file_get_contents("PAIS/".$pais."/EMISORAS.json");

    print_r($datos_emisora);

}
```

?>

y obtengo este resultado

```
[{"pais":"ARGENTINA","emisora":"RADIO-MARIA","id":"A54_050","url":"AHR0CDOVL2RYZWFTC2L0ZXJHZGLVY3AYLMNVBTO4MDA4LZTZDHJLYW0UBNN2JNR5CGU9BXAZ","web":"HTTPS:\/\/RADIOMARIA.ORG.AR\/"},{"pais":"ARGENTINA","emisora":"RADIO-PAN-Y-TRABAJO","id":"A54_012","url":"AHR0CDOVL3MXLNJHZGLVC25LDGHVC3RPBMCUY29TOJK2MJGVO3N0CMVHBS8=","web":"HTTP:\/\/WWW.RADIOPANYTRABAJO.COM.AR"}]
```

necesito en este json obtener solo el valor de la llave URL para luego poder hacer un base64_decode y obtener la direcion en esta. e verificado en el manual de php que esta funcion existe pero no e posiso obtener el valor de la url para poder hacerlo. e intentado hacer un foreach a la variable $datos_emisora pero me devuelve un objeto stdClass objet y cuando trato de obtener solo el valor de el indice url me da el siguiente error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes decodificar el archivo con `json_decode` y luego acceder a los atributos de la manera mas cómoda.

```
    $datos_emisora = file_get_contents("PAIS/".$pais."/EMISORAS.json");
    $datos = json_decode($datos_emisora , true);

    foreach($items as $datos){
      echo $item->url;
    }
```

Comment: en este caso el json puede contener las de un objeto, y el indice url se puede repetir varias veces como puedo hacer si necesito tener todas esas url?

Comment: Ya modifique la respuesta para que iteres sobre las url o los datos que tengas en tu json, sino te funciona con flecha intenta con $item['url']

Comment: me devuelve las 2 url en un solo string

Comment: exacto lo que debes hacer es acomodarlo, ps si tuvieras 3 objetos te va a mostrar 3 urls